# Несколько условий в цикле for

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы в цикле было несколько условий, чтобы они работали не зависимо друг от друга?

```
function test1(){
    if (moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А1"') {
        moAddresLc.value = 'г. Иркутск';
    }
      for (option of moAddresLc) {
        option.style.display = moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А1"' && ~['г. Москва', 'г. Торонто', 'г. Лондон','г. Париж','г.Новосибирск','г. Самара','г. Волгоград'].indexOf(option.innerText) ? 'none' : '';
      }


        
   if (moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А2"') {
            moAddresLc.value = 'г. Самара';
        }
     for (option of moAddresLc) {
            option.style.display = moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А2"' && ~['г. Москва', 'г. Торонто', 'г. Лондон','г. Париж','г.Новосибирск','г. Иркутск','г. Волгоград'].indexOf(option.innerText) ? 'none' : '';
          }
          


   if (moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А3"') {
                moAddresLc.value = 'г. Волгоград';
            }
     for (option of moAddresLc) {
                option.style.display = moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А3"' && ~['г. Москва', 'г. Торонто', 'г. Лондон','г. Париж','г.Новосибирск','г. Самара','г. Иркутск'].indexOf(option.innerText) ? 'none' : '';
              }     
  }
```

HTML

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="moLc" onchange="test1()" title="Введите"><option> ГОРОДА "А1"</option><option> ГОРОДА "А2"</option><option> ГОРОДА "А3"</option></select>

<select class="form-control input-sm" id="moAddresLc" onchange="test2()" title="Введите">
 <option>г. Иркутск</option><option>г. Москва</option><option>г. Торонто</option><option>г. Лондон</option><option>г. Париж</option><option>г.Новосибирск</option><option>г. Самара</option><option>г. Волгоград</option></select>
```

Comment: У вас циклы находятся вне условия `if`. Поместите каждый `for` внутрь нужного `if`, рядом с `moAddresLc.value = `, и должно работать. Сейчас у вас последний `for` перезатирает остальные

Comment: Помещаю for в if все равно работает только последний   1-й if (moLc.value == '') {for () {}}   2-й if (moLc.value == '') {for () {}}

Comment: Все 3 надо вложить, иначе последний будет перезатирать

Comment: Данные if-ы не влияют на циклы. If-ы при выборе выбирают нужный option. Из циклов, срабатывает последний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test1(){
      for (option of moAddresLc) {
        option.style.display = moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А1"' && ~['г. Москва', 'г. Торонто', 'г. Лондон','г. Париж','г.Новосибирск','г. Самара','г. Волгоград'].indexOf(option.innerText) ? 'none' : '' ||

        option.style.display = moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А2"' && ~['г. Москва', 'г. Торонто', 'г. Лондон','г. Париж','г.Новосибирск','г. Иркутск','г. Волгоград'].indexOf(option.innerText) ? 'none' : '' ||

        option.style.display = moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А3"' && ~['г. Москва', 'г. Торонто', 'г. Лондон','г. Париж','г.Новосибирск','г. Самара','г. Иркутск'].indexOf(option.innerText) ? 'none' : '';

}
    if (moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А1"') {
        moAddresLc.value = 'г. Иркутск';
    }

   if (moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А2"') {
            moAddresLc.value = 'г. Самара';
        }
   if (moLc.value == 'ГОРОДА "А3"') {
                moAddresLc.value = 'г. Волгоград';
            }
     }
```